# Matching back ported package versions to major releases

Tags: linux, centos, rpm

Is there a way to link a backported versions of package to what is released by the original developers. For example the latest Centos package for OpenSSL is :

> openssl-1.0.1e-42.el6_7.4.x86_64.rpm

and that maps back to OpenSSL latest release which is :

> 1.0.1s

Is there a mapping all the other backported versions of this package or any package?

Comment: Given that the idea with backporting in this case is to take specific fixes and merging them into an older code base, I doubt it. **What problem are you trying to solve** by doing this? There may very well be a better way.

Comment: I have older OS versions of packages and was wondering if I can help coordinate to the release version of the original group. People seem to take that info in easier vs. telling them about the different os version numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the answer is **no**.

You *should* be able to keep track of the backported features using the package log/revision, but nothing more.

Comment: That is what I have been doing but was wondering if there was something else. Thank you.